# How do I pass a captured image from react native camera to another screen using navigation(version 5)

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-image

I  followed the documentation it worked but using image data returned after capturing doesn't appear on the new screen. I have searched but not getting any solution for navigating image data.

[this is the code for passing the image data to the next screen, alongside a test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgpVv.png)

[the screen for receiving the captured image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlEJr.png)

[receiving the captured image in an image component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKGi2.png)

[passing image data to state(path and pathBase64)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut8GD.png)

Answer (score 1):

navigate to the screen using this code, here imageFile is the state where you stored your image after capturing from the camera.

`props.navigation.navigate("navigation_route",{image: imageFile})`

then, use this code to fetch the image on the other screen.

```
let image = props.navigation.getParam('image')
```

Comment: I get  TypeError: navigation.getParam is not a function, navigation.getParam is undefined.

Comment: which react-navigation version you are using?

Comment: I  am using react-navigation version 5.x
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Comment: use this code then,   
  const { itemId } = props.route.params;

Comment: I did that it didn't work(appear on the next screen) for the image data being passed, but worked for a test which I passed alongside the image data.

Comment: you might be not passing image date properly, can you upload the code where you are storing the image in your state?

Comment: simply pass the uri to your next screen and in Image tag simply write that variable
source={{uri: passedUri}}

Comment: Thanks, Sardar through your contribution I figured it out.
passed the base64 of the image data
 onPressOut={()=> {navigation.navigate('EvidenceSubmission' ,
                   {
                      transferredImage: camState.pathBase64,
                      
                    })}}

received it on the next screen as
 source= { {uri: `data:image/jpeg;base64, ${transferredImage}`}}

Comment: but the image delays some seconds before appearing the next screen

Answer (score 0):

to receive the image in the next screen use the below code

```
let image = props.route.params.image
```

Answer (score 0):

screen to send the image
function: navigation.navigate('RouteName', {imageTobeTransferred:
state.imageInBase64})

receiving Screen.
const { imageTobeTransferred } = route.params;
return(
<Image style={{...}}
source= { {uri: `data:image/jpeg;base64, ${imageTobeTransferred}`}}/>
)